# Can Yii correctly utilize urlManager rules with the createUrl function?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, yii

I have a series of **urlManager** rules that simplify my web application. For example, the vanilla application installer that comes with Yii creates the 'page' model and I redirect pages from */site/page/view/about* to */about*.

This works great, but I am not sure if Yii is capable of reading my rules to determine the best URL to create. Currently, **createUrl** will return the standard URL (*/site/page/view/about*) if I use the following code: 
`createUrl('/site/page', array('view'=>'about'))`

Alternatively, using `createUrl('/about')` will link to the preferred URL correctly, but this does not seem as good practice as the first example. Also, using this in the **CMenu** function will not associate this link as the current *active* link.

Is there better practice to follow for this requirement? The alternative use of **createUrl** seems overly 'hard coded' and, as noted, doesn't work logically with the system (determining the active page, etc).

Comment: Can you please post the url rules? and note that the correct syntax for `createUrl` is `createUrl('site/page', array('view'=>'about'))`

Comment: @dlnGd0nG The rule in question is `'<page:\w+>' => 'site/page/view/<page>'`. Sorry, that was a typo for my **createUrl** function, in my script it's usage is correct, as you stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule `'<page:\w+>' => 'site/page/view/<page>'` is incorrect. Use this (assuming you are using the default gii generated code) as the first rule

```
'<view:\w+>'=>'site/page'
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it, now creatUrl, etc, returns the desired url. Do you have a reference I can read for how this works? The examples I have looked at always make use of the 'string variable' (eg. the <view> tag has to be used in the rule assignment, how else does it know the page? or is this assumed with the name of this variable?).

Comment: Beyond this, how would this rule work for a second-level page (eg, */staff/john-smith*, found in *site/pages/staff/john-smith*? I can't seem to make the rule include forward slashes (even when changing it to `<view>` or `<view:.+>`

Comment: refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url . and the key(`view` in above) is the GET parameter and the value (`'site/page'`)is the route(means controller/action)

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to create url: /site/page/view/about

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page', array('view'=>'about'));
```

It is mentioned in better way here : [Yii Url Mmanagement](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

Comment: This is the standard way and results in the original, full-form URL (`/site/page/view/about`), not the rule version unfortunately